# Calculate linear velicity at a point in a rotating object

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotation

If I have an object $A$ rotating at an angular velocity $w$, how would I calculate the linear velocity $v(x, y)$ of a certain point $r(x, y)$ in the object?

Comment: At first shot [in wiki gives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_velocity) -$\mathbf {v} _{\perp }={\boldsymbol {\omega }}\times \mathbf {r}$.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it like this - if the entire object is rotating with angular velocity $\omega = 2\pi/T$ (presumably about the origin), that means each point on the object travels a distance $2\pi R$ in a time $T$, where $R$ is the distance from the origin to that point. The speed of the object is of course constant, and therefore the linear speed at any point on the object will be $v = 2\pi R / T = R\omega$. Now we simply plug in $R = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and get

$$v(x,y) = \omega R(x,y) = \omega \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the center of rotation, point **C**, and some arbitrary point **A** with coordinates $(x,y)$. If the rotational speed is $\Omega$ then point **A** is going to orbit around **C**.

[image: fig1]

The velocity of point **A** is a vector perpendicular to *CA* and by analyzing the similar triangles they form (look at the angle $\theta$) you find the velocity vector of **A** to be

$$ v_A = \pmatrix{-y\, \Omega \\ x\, \Omega} $$

The speed of **A** is $$ \| v_A \| = \sqrt{ (-y \Omega)^2 + (x \Omega)^2} = \Omega \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

which is the product of the rotational speed $\Omega$ and the distance to **A**.